# Mapping with square bracket

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-unite.vim

I am looking at some plugin that happens to be configurable through a curious mapping (e.g. [unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt#L210-L232)):

```
More advanced configuration example:
>
    " The prefix key.
    nnoremap    [unite]   <Nop>
    nmap    f [unite]

    nnoremap <silent> [unite]c  :<C-u>UniteWithCurrentDir
            \ -buffer-name=files buffer bookmark file<CR>
```

What does the `[unite]` means ?

I understand that it stands for a custom leader/prefix only for the plugin, but what is it's meaning for Vim ?

Comment: The way I see it, it's a clever way to create a custom leader. If you only press `f` in your example, it will be resolved to `[unite]` (due to the `nmap`), which in turn resolves to `<Nop>`, i.e. nothing, but only after the map timeout, or if **not** followed by one of the defined combinations, such as `c`, in which case it suddenly turns into `[unite]c`, which resolves to the mapped command :) Basically, `f` turns to nothing, but `fc` turns to the mapped command. `[unite]` is just a convenient placeholder, you can use other text if you want. Vim won't interpret its characters individually.

Comment: OK I see, this is indeed really clever. What about the `[` square bracket `]` ? Does they means "treats this as one symbol" ?

Comment: Nope, they are no more special than any other characters. They are for your eyes only, to look like a prefix key. :)

Comment: So I can imagine `nnoremap myprefix <nop>` and then using `myprefix` anywhere ? or using `{}` instead ?

Comment: @VanLaser: do you want to make an answer to this question? I'll do it otherwise

Comment: Do it, please :) There is a side-effect of choosing a certain 'prefix' - e.g. `[unite]` could affect a map defined in the same buffer, made from its first letters (e.g. `[u`) in that Vim will now wait to see if you type `n` after it, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion with [VanLaser](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1800/vanlaser), it seems that the `[unite]` mapping is used only with a combination of another key.

Let's break down the mappings:

```
nnoremap    [unite]   <Nop>
```

Map `[unite]` to nothing.

```
nmap    f [unite]
```

Map `f` to `[unite]`. At this point if we press `f`, nothing will happen, as `[unite]` is mapped to `<nop>`.

But when we add a `[unite]`-based mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> [unite]c  :<C-u>UniteWithCurrentDir ...
```

Then the `[unite]c` (which will be triggered by pressing `fc`) will call the desired command. If the `f` key is pressed alone, after the map timeout, nothing will append as it will be translated to `[unite]` alone.